# Find duplicated code in overridden method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-cleanup, duplicate-detection

Is there any program which can find duplicated code in  a base method and overridden methods in inherited classes?

I have a base class for 20 classes that has about 30 virtual methods (I didn't write this code). I found one method that has almost the same code in all overrides. I think this same situation is occurring in other methods.

How can I find duplicated code blocks so that I can refactor it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select the code in the visual studio editor. Right click-> Select *Find matching clones in solution*. Give it some time to process. It will tell you identical code in your solution.

[Finding Duplicate Code by using Code Clone Detection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh205279.aspx) . As noted in comments, this feature is available only in Ultimate and Premium versions of visual studio.

Resharper has something similar.  Select the code,  Right click-> Select *Find similar code* menu.

Comment: You might want to mention that this is only available in Visual Studio Ultimate or Visual Studio Premium.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Resharper DupFinder, perhaps? It's part of their command line tools.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2013/09/03/duplicate-finder-part-of-resharper-command-line-tools/